# "Exactly" 3 lines in $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = (x+y+z)^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm just browsing through at Andreas Gathman's lecture notes in algebraic geometry, and I've managed to confuse myself right at the start, on question 0.2.4:

> Exercise 0.2.4. Let $S$ be the specific cubic surface
> $S = \{(x, y, z) ~ ;  ~x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = (x + y + z)^3 \} ⊂ \mathbb{C}^3$ .
>
> (i) Show that there are exactly 3 lines contained in $S$.

Well, $S$ is equivalent to $\{(x,y,z) ~ ; ~ (x+y)(x+z)(y+z) = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{C}^3$,

but the vanishing of each factor just gives us a plane, rather than a complex line right? I.e. $\{x+y = 0$, $z \in \mathbb{C} \}$ is just $\mathbb{C}^2$. So we have an infinite family of lines -- or even 3 such families, from the vanishing of the other linear factors. I'll grant that the intersection of any two planes is a unique line (e.g. $x=-y=z$), but there are surely far more than those 3 intersections.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here ...

Comment: Is it possible that the author meant to consider $S$ as a subset of $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^3)$ ? In this case, your three planes yield three lines in the projective space...

Comment: @GreginGre Would that it were the case, you can see the notes themselves here https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002.pdf (page 7 or 10 depending how you count)

Comment: @MichaelWeiss I'm not sure I follow, the second would give $2xyz$, and I've dropped an overall factor of $3$ since I don't believe it makes a difference.

Comment: @GreginGre Also, it's strange as in $\mathbb{P}^3$, we would have projective coordinates $[x:y:z:w]$, but the affine equation here is already homogeneous, but in just 3 variables. It would be more "pleasant" if it were e.g. $1 +x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = (1 + x + y +z)^3$, which would be the affine version of the Clebsch surface. I guess this is just a degenerate surface, in the way that a pair of lines is a degenerate conic.

Comment: I don't believe it's a smooth cubic surface, so not required to have 27 lines on it. I notice that this example has disappeared from more recent versions of the notes; perhaps it wasn't correct.

Comment: @mcd Yes, I think that's what's going on, especially with it being dropped in the newer notes.